# Combine browse an image and upload

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

See below code. There are two buttons. One button is to select an image and the second button is to upload the selected image. So first the user browse an image and then secondly the user clicks on the UPLOAD IMAGE button to upload.

How can I combine these two together. So when the user browse an image, the uploading also automatically follows. Basically instead of two clicks I want this to happen in a single click.

```
<form name="picUp" method="post" id="pic_uploads" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="well">
<label for="file">Your Picture:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

Note: I'm using bootstrap 3.0 here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the on change event

With JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $("#file").change(function (){
       $("#pic_uploads").submit();
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the "onchange" attribute in your file input:
`<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="document.getElementById('pic_uploads').submit()">`